# UIApplication.keywindow ,must be used from main thread only warning

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift4, dispatch, uiapplication

[image]

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
}
```

This cause error in my Extension
[image]

How I use it

```
 let topController = UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to like below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let topController = UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()
}
```

or alternatively you can use block. You can’t return directly from async operation.

```
func topMostViewController(onSuccess: (UIViewController) -> ()) {

...
}
```